# Showing both sides of the percentage?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the formula to figure out percentages, that's not the problem, basic

- A1 = 7
- B1 = 500

So if we do `=A1/B1` the answer should be 0.014

What I want to show now is the other side of it, the 99.986.

I thought the formula would be easy, but my brain for some reason isn't figuring it out.  In math it should be the answer should be answer-100, but that doesn't seem to be accepting it in excel.

Anyt help would be appreciated, I've gone through so many complex formulas as of late, my brain just can't wrap myself around simple calculations any more for some reason.

Comment: `=1-A1/B1`... 100% is 1.

Comment: BTW: `0.014` <> `0.014%` it is `1.4%` and as such the inverse would be `98.6%`

Comment: @ScottCraner so, the formula to show the 98.6 is?

Comment: What @BigBen showed in his comment.